# loaded form in div, button won't run click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#stusel").change(onSelectChangest);
 $("#schoolsel").change(onSelectChangesc);
 $("#coachsel").change(onSelectChangeco);
 var selval = 0;
 //
 function onSelectChangest(){
   var selected = $("#stusel option:selected");
 //    alert ('Student Selected ' + selected.val());
   selval = selected.val();
   var usertype = '1';
   var pdata = {'usertype' : '1' , 'formtype': selected.val() };
   loadform(pdata);
 };
 // form load function
    function loadform(pdata) {
   $('#msg1').load(
     'makeform.php',
     pdata,
     function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
       var tstring = responseText.split('~$~');
       var thestatus = tstring[0];
       var theform = tstring[1];
       if (selval == 4) { // not coded for selection 4 yet
       }
       if (thestatus == 1) {
     // insert the form in the form div
         $('#display').html(theform);
     // open the form div
         $('#dispbox').removeClass('hideme');
     // run the process to make the form live
         loadformjs(selval);
       } else {
         $('#dispbox').addClass('hideme');
         $('#display').html('');
       }
     }
   );
 }
 //loadformjs
 function loadformjs(form) {
 $('#submitme').unbind('click');
 switch (form) {
 case '1':  //login
  $('#submitme').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var user = 'login_name='+ escape($('#uname').val());
  var upass = '&login_pass='+ escape($('#upass').val());
  var utype = '&user_type='+ usertype;
  var pdata = user+upass+utype;
  $.ajax({
    type   : "POST",
    cache  : false,
    url    : "login.php",
    data   : pdata,
    success: function(data) {
     var tstring = data.split('~');
     sysmsg = tstring[1];
     userdata = tstring[2];
     jQuery.cookie( 'userdata', userdata );
     }
    });
  });
 break;
 case '2':   //register
  alert ('loaded theform');
  $('#submitme').click(function(e) {
    alert('before ajax call');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
 break;
 }
} //snipped code here.... Theres more cases, etc.
```

Now the process is that the user selects an action from the pulldown, that action causes a form to be loaded in a div, when the form is loaded the div is displayed and then the loadformjs is run. The first thing that it does is unbind the button used for submit, then it should rebind the button.

I get the alert that the form is loaded.
I get the alert that the loadqueryjs is run
but when I use the button there doesn't appear to be any action associated to the click since the alert for the click does not run.

The form would look something like:

```
<center><h1>Registration</h1></center>
<form id=userform>
    <input type=hidden id=usertype value=".$usertype." name=usertype>
    <table border=0>
        <tr><td colspan=2> <center><h3>Required by HSCETP</h3></center></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Your School Code </td><td>
            <input type=text id=scode1 name=scode1 size=10> -
            <input type=text id=scode2 name=scode2 size=10> -
            <input type=text id=scode3 name=scode3 size=10>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td> Your e-mail (login) </td><td> <input type=text id=email name=email size=50></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Repeat your e-mail (login) </td><td> <input type=text name=emailr size=50></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Your Password </td><td> <input type=password id=password name=password size=50></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Repeat your Password </td><td> <input type=password name=password1 size=50></td></tr>
        ".$reqgrade."
        ".$reqbook."
        ".$reqid."
        <tr><td colspan=2> <center><h3>Optional</h3></center></td></tr>
        ".$optzip."
        <tr><td> Your Name </td><td> <input type=text id=uname name=uname size=50></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2> <button type=button id=submitme>Submit</button>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>
            Each user account yadd yada yada - general text
        </td></tr>
        ".$adminwarn."
    </table>
</form>
```

now the:

```
<button type=button id=submitme>Submit</button>
```

was

```
 <button id=submitme>Submit</button>
```

but that caused the form to submit so I added the type=button, but now I get nothing.

The workflow is:

- user selects action from select list
- jquery called gets form via ajax loads form into div, displays div, calls loadformjs
- loadformjs unbinds the submitme id and then based on the case, rebinds the
  submitme id to a new click function
- user completes form, uses the button to submit and the form is submitted to ajax for processing and then, based on the form, specific actions happen (like on a successful registration the user also gets logged in)

so, why is the form that has been loaded into the div not binding to the submitme id and submitting on the click?

Comment: have you heard about **delegated events**?

Comment: Is ID `submitme` unique on page?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad even though delegated event is more appropriate way for dynamic elements, I don't see why OP code shouldn't work.

Comment: as OP saying that content is loading via ajax call]

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `click` event handler is binding _after_ dynamic content was added to page, so it should work.

Comment: @Regent has the flow right. The jquery that attaches to the event is loaded after the html is loaded to the dom. The alerts show that the loading process is happening in the appropriate order as the selection brings up the first alert (loading the form), the form loads and displays and then the second alert is fired (loading the jquery for the click event). The ONLY submitme ID is loaded within the form (all the form blocks will use the same submitme id for the button submission).

Comment: @met00 do you really mean _all the form blocks will use the same submitme id_? Elements IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: @Regent user selects appropriate form, A form block is loaded via ajax to the div, the click event is unbind (unbound?), the click event is then bind'ed (bound) to the new form button.

Comment: [attempted edit, but time ran out]
The other option is to place the button outside the form and in the div. Associate the click event to the button on page load, then load the form in the div, expose the div and have the submitme button outside the form and NOT loaded with each form but always there. But, the loading of the form and then  the jquery afterwards and associating the event to the button after the form loads *should* work!

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was loading the form in the div. The answer was to change the way that the ajax loaded the page. Instead of

```
<form id=userform>
<input type=hidden id=usertype value=".$usertype." name=usertype>
<table border=0>
    <tr><td colspan=2> <center><h3>Required by HSCETP</h3></center></td></tr>
    <tr><td> Your School Code </td><td>
        <input type=text id=scode1 name=scode1 size=10> -
        <input type=text id=scode2 name=scode2 size=10> -
        <input type=text id=scode3 name=scode3 size=10>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Your e-mail (login) </td><td> <input type=text id=email name=email size=50></td></tr>
    <tr><td> Repeat your e-mail (login) </td><td> <input type=text name=emailr size=50 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Your Password </td><td> <input type=password id=password name=password size=50></td></tr>
    <tr><td> Repeat your Password </td><td> <input type=password name=password1 size=50></td></tr>
    ".$reqgrade."
    ".$reqbook."
    ".$reqid."
    <tr><td colspan=2> <center><h3>Optional</h3></center></td></tr>
    ".$optzip."
    <tr><td> Your Name </td><td> <input type=text id=uname name=uname size=50></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2> <button type=button id=submitme>Submit</button>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2>
        Each user account yadd yada yada - general text
    </td></tr>
    ".$adminwarn."
</table>
</form>
```

put the form in the first program and then load the form id from the ajax call.

The end result is

```
<div id=dispbox class=hideme>
<table border=3 width=100%>
 <tr><td>
 <form id=userform>
 </form>
 <tr><td colspan=2> <button type=button id=submitme>Submit</button>
 </td></tr></table>
 </div>
```

and the code to the ajax is

```
function loadform(pdata) {
   $('#msg1').load(
     'makeform.php',
     pdata,
     function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
       var tstring = responseText.split('~$~');
       var thestatus = tstring[0];
       var theform = tstring[1];
       var thebutton = tstring[2];
       if (thestatus == 1) {
  // insert the form in the form div
         $('#userform').html(theform);
         $('#submitme').html(thebutton);
   // open the form div
         $('#dispbox').removeClass('hideme');
       } else {
         $('#dispbox').addClass('hideme');
       }
     }
   );
  }
```

Now the code to activate the submit button can run through a case statement that just sets the appropriate ajax program to submit to based on the form

Using this method permits all forms to be loaded in a div, all process of the form to be completed by a single button push, and rather than processing each forms input uniquely I used jquery.form.js to send the forms over with a case statement in the beforesubmit to reset the program being called and post processing in the aftersubmit.

So, the basic rule is... you can't load a form in a div into the page and then process the jquery against it. It appears to be a dom issue.